# ¿Cómo puedo instalar una versión de pip diferente a la de python3.8.1? (Ubunutu)

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

He estado utilizando Ubuntu recientemente y por defecto viene con python3.8.1. El problema está en que cuando quiero instalar una versión de pip para python3.10 con el comando `sudo apt install python3.10-pip` me da un error, y si coloco `sudo apt install python3-pip` instala el de python3.8.1, ya que es él por defecto. ¿Alguien que me ayude?.

Comment: prueba con `sudo apt install python3-pip==la_version`

Comment: Hey, intente con sudo apt install python3-pip==3.10 y da este error: Unable to locate package python3-pip=

Comment: También intenté sudo apt install python3.10-pip==3.10 y da este error: Unable to locate package python3.10-pip=

Comment: verifica que la versión de pip exista y este disponble. Tambien puedes instalar la versión por defecto y luego actualizarla a la mas reciente con `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: La versión de pip que instales debe coincidir con la versión de python instalada. Es más, ni siquiera necesitas instalar pip. Puedes usar en su lugar `python -m pip` y así te aseguras de que se está usando la versión correcta (que sería la misma que la de python en ese comando)

Comment: @Christian La versión de pip 3.10 no la tengo instalada. Al ejecutar el comando y poner `pip3 -- version` arroja esto: `pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

Comment: @abulafia al poner python3 -m pip sí que funciona. Pero al poner python3.10 -m pip me da un error.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando `pip3` (y deseas seguir usándolo), puedes usar los siguientes comandos:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade pip3
```

Entiendo que esto debe actualizar Pip.